# Prevent sorting with for-in loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON array sorted by type (rather than ID).

```
var response = {"5":"Contacts","2":"Messages","3":"Profiles","1":"Schools","4":"Statistics"};
for (var key in response) {
    alert(key + ' ' + response[key]);
}
```

I am wanting the order to stay as is however what is happening is that it is sorting it by ID so that it produces "1 Schools" first. How do I prevent a for-in loop from sorting by key?

I realize that no sorting order is guaranteed with a for-in loop, so how do I get around this? I need to access both the key and type. Is there a different type of array and/or loop that I should be using instead?

Also, just for further clarification and in case it makes a difference, my actual code has the JSON array coming from an AJAX request from PHP using json_encode.

Comment: [No order is guaranteed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for `for...in` loops.

Comment: Do you have access on the server? If you could make the response an array instead of an object it could work for you. A response like [{key:5, value:Contacts}...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have an array, you have an object. Key ordering in an object is not guaranteed in javascript. If you want a sorted collection, you should use an actual array:

```
var response = [{"key":"5", "value":"Contacts"},{"key":"2", "value":"Messages"},{"key":"3", "value":"Profiles"},{"key":"1", "value":"Schools"},{"key":"4", "value":"Statistics"}];
for (var i =0; i < response.length; i++) {
    alert(response[i].key + ' ' + response[i].value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was using an associative array in PHP, I had to change this to an indexed array containing associative arrays for each index. This allowed json_encode to convert it to a proper JavaScript array rather than a JavaScript object. I did not realize that it was an object to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I prevent a for-in loop from sorting by key?

You can't. The iteration order is unspecified and implementation depended<sup>1</sup>. If you need to traverse your data in a predefined order, use an array instead.

---

1: Most popular browsers will iterate over numeric properties in ascending order and then non-numeric properties in insertion order, but again, that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the server but the order of the key is guaranteed you can try the following:

Map the keys in the order you want them and loop them that way

```
var response = {"5":"Contacts","2":"Messages","3":"Profiles","1":"Schools","4":"Statistics"};
var map = ["5","2","3","1","4"]; 
for(var i = 0; i < map.length;i++){
    alert(i+' '+response[map[i]])
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `response[map[i]]`?